# Load an SVG to a P5 sketch

Tags: svg, processing, shapes, p5.js

I've been programming in Processing some time now.
I've also worked with shapes and `SVG` files.
Having this humble experience regarding `SVG` files in Processing made me think that it would be the same story in `P5.js`, which is clearly not the case and makes me seek for help.

Back in Processing I would just have simple code like this:

```java
PShape shape;
/***************************************************************************/
void setup() 
{
  size(400, 400);
  shapeMode(CENTER);
  shape = loadShape("bot1.svg");
} 
/***************************************************************************/
void draw() 
{
  background(100);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  shape(shape, 0, 0);
  popMatrix();
}
```

`P5` doesn't work that way.
What would be the `P5.js` equivalent to that?

```
    var shape;
    var canvas;
/***************************************************************************/
    function setup() 
    {
      canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
      canvas.position(0, 0);
      //shapeMode(CENTER);
      //shape = loadShape("bot1.svg");
    } 
    /***************************************************************************/
    void draw() 
    {
      background(100);
      push();
      translate(width/2, height/2);
      //shape(shape, 0, 0);
      pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P5.js does not support loading SVG files out of the box. [Here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/458) is a discussion on GitHub containing a ton of information about this.

Processing.js does support SVG files though. More info in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/loadShape_/).

You've tagged your question with [processing.js](/questions/tagged/processing.js), but I think you were originally asking about [p5.js](/questions/tagged/p5.js). But note that Processing.js and P5.js are two completely different things.

Comment: I hoped there was a simple way. Thanks for the correction also :)

Comment: What would you recommend me, continue with P5.js or change to Processing.js?.

Comment: @Zardoz That's completely up to you. It depends on how badly you need SVG support. Note that Processing.js isn't really actively developed anymore.

Comment: Understood. I'll go for the P5 then and try to figure out a solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Zardoz Also note that you aren't doing anything with the actual shape in your example, so you might just convert your SVG into a PNG or JPG image and use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Kevin's answer, if you do want load and SVG in p5.js you should check out [p5.js-svg](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) and the [svg manipulation example](http://zenozeng.github.io/p5.js-svg/examples/#manipulating)

[image: p5.js SVG]

As a quick'n'dirty start you can try this:

1. Download [p5.svg.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg/master/dist/p5.svg.js) to the p5. sketch libraries folder
2. Import it in index.html: `<script src="libraries/p5.svg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
3. Create an SVG Canvas: `createCanvas(600, 200, SVG);`

Comment: That is really helpful. The problem is that Chrome, or any other navigator, won't let me display the file (even if it was PNG or JPG).

Comment: Feel free to vote up the answer if it was helpful. Regarding displaying the file ? How are you displaying the file ? If you simply have an html file that you open in the browser without serving it, you will get an error similar to this:“Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.”. You will need to run a the code on a web server. You can easily run a local web server and there are plenty of options depending on your OS (e.g. XAMPP/MAMP/python SimpleHTTPServer/etc.). The simplest I can think of is actually using the [p5.js editor](http://p5js.org/download/) which handles this for you.